# Missing Partial error in view spec generated by scaffold in rails 3.1.10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, partial, scaffold

I just generated a scaffold in rails 3.1.10 and when I run rspec I get the following error:

```
Failures:   1) organizations/edit.html.erb renders the edit organization form
     Failure/Error: render
     Missing partial /form with {:handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]}. Searched in:
       * "/home/ubuntu/Documents/github/LocalSupport/app/views"
     # ./app/views/organizations/edit.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_organizations_edit_html_erb__643434798_103899540'
     # ./spec/views/organizations/edit.html.erb_spec.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) organizations/new.html.erb renders new organization form
     Failure/Error: render
     Missing partial /form with {:handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]}. Searched in:
       * "/home/ubuntu/Documents/github/LocalSupport/app/views"
     # ./app/views/organizations/new.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_organizations_new_html_erb__277486420_91000650'
     # ./spec/views/organizations/new.html.erb_spec.rb:17:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.68276 seconds 29 examples, 2 failures, 2 pending
```

It seems that the spec can't find the form partial when it runs render.  Here's the failing part in the rails generated spec (it fails when it reaches the "render" keyword):

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "organizations/index.html.erb" do
  before(:each) do
    assign(:organizations, [
      stub_model(Organization,
        :name => "Name",
        :address => "Address",
        :postcode => "Postcode",
        :email => "Email",
        :description => "Description",
        :website => "",
        :telephone => "Telephone"
      ),
      stub_model(Organization,
        :name => "Name",
        :address => "Address",
        :postcode => "Postcode",
        :email => "Email",
        :description => "Description",
        :website => "",
        :telephone => "Telephone"
      )
    ])
  end

  it "renders a list of organizations" do
    render
    # Run the generator again with the --webrat-matchers flag if you want to use webrat matchers
    assert_select "tr>td", :text => "Name".to_s, :count => 2
```

I've searched around this on google but can't find anything specific to this scaffold.  I've found this SO post:

[Rails: "missing partial" when calling 'render' in RSpec test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425662/rails-missing-partial-when-calling-render-in-rspec-test)

but it seems to suggest that render is the right way to go, i.e. the scaffold is correct.  Any ideas?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found at least a temporary solution which is to add the following to the spec before the render operation:

view.lookup_context.prefixes = %w[organizations application]

based on this documented rails issue here:

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/5213

Answer (score 0):

The file "./app/views/organizations/edit.html" has a call at line 3 which probably reads something like

render "form"  which can equate to =>  "organizations/_form.html.erb"

this file is missing....

you can either provide one or edit the line out in edit.html(.erb/.haml)

Comment: that file is present: saasbook@saasbook:~/Documents/github/LocalSupport$ ls app/views/organizations/
edit.html.erb  _form.html.erb  index.html.erb  new.html.erb  show.html.erb - the problem is that it is searching in the wrong place - look closely at the error message - you will see it says 'Searched in: "/home/ubuntu/Documents/github/LocalSupport/app/views"'  it is not looking in /home/ubuntu/Documents/github/LocalSupport/app/views/organizations where it should be - I am trying to figure out how to fix that ...